# How to set spinner to a specific value when using custom Adapter

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a spinner that I am filling with data from a table. So I am using a custom made adapter because I need to be able to show one column but the data I will store in a table is from another column. Say I have a table called color. it has an ID field and Desc field. So my spinner will show Red, Green, Blue, Black when you select a color I needed to grab the ID for that color and store it. I have the spinner made and working fine. I created a custome adapter to pull in the table here is my adapter.

```
class SpinnerAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private IEnumerable<Color> _Color;
    private Activity _context;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, IEnumerable<Color> Color)
    {
        _context = context;
        _Color = Color;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, 
                                 ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = (convertView ?? _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(
            Resource.Layout.SpinnerList, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;
        var Color = _Color.ElementAt(position);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ID).Text = 
            Color.ColorCd.ToString();
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TimeID).Text =
            Color.ColorDesc.ToString();

        return view;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _Color.Count(); }
    }

    public Color GetColor(int position)
    {
        return _Color.ElementAt(position);
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
}
```

In my Activity page I set my adapter to the spinner like so;

```
Spinner spAdapter = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spAdapter);
spAdapter.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs>(spAdapter_ItemClick);
var Color = ((LeavApplication)Application).LeaveRepository.GetAllColor();
spAdapter.Adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, Color);
```

That part all works fine. but if I have a value I want the spinner set to how do I do it. for example I want to set the value of the spinner to "Blue" how do I find the possition of Blue so that I can use the SetSelection function to set the spinner. Is there a function I need to create in my adapter and what would it be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the color list yourself and can then use SetSelection on the spinner?

e.g.:

```
  Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spAdapter);
  spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs>(spAdapter_ItemClick);
  var colors = ((LeavApplication)Application).LeaveRepository.GetAllColor().ToList();
  spinner.Adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, colors);
  spinner.SetSelection(colors.IndexOf(TheColorIWant));
```

Comment: This gets an error on IndexOf: the error is 'Android.widget.spinner' does not contain a definition for IndexOf and no extention method 'IndexOf' accepting a first argument of type Android.widget.spinner

Comment: The code I put up had `colors.IndexOf`, not `spinner.IndexOf`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer that is working for me. In my custom Adapter "SpinnerAdapter.cs" I added a function.

```
public int GetPosition(string value)
{
  int i = 0;
  foreach (var item in _Color)
  {
    if (item.ColorDesc == value)
    {
      return i;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Then in my Activity page I could add this.

```
  Spinner spAdapter = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spAdapter);
  spAdapter.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs>(spAdapter_ItemClick);
  var Color = ((LeavApplication)Application).LeaveRepository.GetAllColor();
  spAdapter.Adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, Color);

  // Set the spinner with preDefined value
  string sColor = "Green";
  int iPosition = ((SpinnerAdapter)spAdapter.Adapter).GetPosition(sColor);
  FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spAdapter).SetSelection(iPosition);
```

And it is setting the selected item to the predetermind color.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following method in the main body

```
        int itemPosition = spinnerConsultationDegreeAdapter.GetItemPosition(request.ConsultationDegreeId);
        spinnerConsultationDegree.SetSelection(itemPosition);
```

Then add a function corresponding adapter

```
    public int GetItemPosition(int consultationDegreeId)
    {
        var degree = _consultationDegrees.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == consultationDegreeId);
        var position = _consultationDegrees.IndexOf(degree);
        return position;
    }
```